# WebappLoader vs WebappClassLoader in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, classloader

What is the purpose of having `WebappLoader` and `WebappClassLoader` in Tomcat?
As I understand `WebappClassLoader` is per web application and `WebAppLoader` for tomcat server instance.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**You are wrong:**

- `WebAppLoader` is MBean, it is not a ClassLoader
- `WebappClassLoader` is a real ClassLoader implementation